# How find this the value of $\log_{3}|(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}})^{2000}+(\overline{z_{1}}z_{2})^{2000}|=?$

Tags: complex-numbers

let $z_{1},z_{2}\in C$,and such
$$|z_{1}|=|z_{1}+z_{2}|=3,|z_{1}-z_{2}|=3\sqrt{3}$$

Find the value of $$\log_{3}|(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}})^{2000}+(\overline{z_{1}}z_{2})^{2000}|=?$$

My try:since 
$$|z_{1}|=|z_{1}+z_{2}|=3,|z_{1}-z_{2}|=3\sqrt{3}$$
then we let
$z_{1}=a+bi,z_{2}=c+di$

then
$$a^2+b^2=9,|z_{1}+z_{2}|^2=(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2=9,(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2=27$$
then
$$(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)=36$$
so
$$c^2+d^2=9$$
then
$$|z_{1}|=|z_{2}|=3$$
so
$$(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}})^{2000}=[(a+bi)(c-di)]^{2000}=(ac+bd+(bc-ad)i)^{2000}$$
Then I can't ,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let $z_i = 3\cdot w_i$, $i =1,2$. Then you get

$$\log_3 \lvert (z_1\overline{z}_2)^{2000} + (\overline{z}_1z_2)^{2000}\rvert = 4000 + \log_3 \lvert (w_1\overline{w}_2)^{2000} + (\overline{w}_1w_2)^{2000}\rvert$$

and have $\lvert w_1\rvert = \lvert w_1+w_2\rvert = 1$ and $\lvert w_1 - w_2\rvert = \sqrt{3}$. Write $w = \overline{w}_1w_2$. Then you have $\lvert 1+w\rvert = 1$ and $\lvert 1-w\rvert = \sqrt{3}$. Elementary geometry tells us that $w = e^{\pm2\pi i/3}$, and hence $w^3 = 1$, and

$$w^{2000} + \overline{w}^{2000} = w^2 + \overline{w}^2 = \overline{w} + w = -1,$$

so $\log_3 \lvert \overline{w}^{2000} + w^{2000}\rvert = 0$, so altogether

$$\log_3 \lvert (z_1\overline{z}_2)^{2000} + (\overline{z}_1z_2)^{2000}\rvert = 4000.$$